# reactjs vs razor in asp.net - which one is better for seo?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, razor

Please give a brief explanation

Which one is better for SEO websites?

javad

Comment: If SEO is your concern, there might be many more considerations to make before this one.  The effect of framework choice on SEO is pretty much governed by how it's used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReactJS based apps can be indexed by search engines just like ASP.NET, by applying Server Side Rendering. For ReactJS you might want to consider to base your solution on [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/learn/), a solid and proven Server Side Rendering framework built on top of ReactJS.